# Delete cascade or trigger für Multiple Cascade Path with nullable foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I've a problem with the delete-actions in a table-structure with Multiple Cascade Path's.
I know, the theme is often discussed here and a good description/solution can be found e.g. in
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger  with the solution to use an INSTEAD OF Trigger.

But my table structure is a little bit different because of a **nullable**-foreign key. The next image shows the **desired** structure:

```
                            +-----------------+                       +----------------+
    +------(fk not null)----| ProductionSteps |<-----(fk not null)----| CUSTOMER-TABLE |
    |     delete cascade    +-----------------+     delete cascade    +----------------+
    |                                ^
    V                                |
+--------------------+          (fk nullable)
|  ProductionOrders  |        on delete set null
+--------------------+               |
    ^                                |
    |                       +-----------------+
    +------(fk not null)----| ProcessingData  |
          delete cascade    +-----------------+
```

And I don't want to use an INSTEAD OF Delete-Trigger for the ProductionSteps-Table because my tables are part of a delivered software product and the customer can extend the system with additional tables, e.g. a CUSTOMER-TABLE with an fk to ProductionSteps (delete cascade).
So by using the INSTEAD OF Trigger the customer has to extend the delivered Trigger for his CUSTOMER-TABLE and therefore the trigger isn't updatable.
Also the customer isn't familiar with triggers.
So I hope there's an alternative solution.

The sql-commands for creating the tables and testdata are added at the end. Inside there are also a detailed description including the error messages.
Environment: SQLServer 2016

The **desired** foreign keys are (like shown in the image):

- ProductionSteps: fk to ProductionOrders (not null,  delete cascade)
- ProcessingData   1. fk to ProductionOrders (not null,  delete
  cascade) and 2. fk to ProductionSteps (**nullable, on delete set
  null**)

Because of the multiple cascade path's, the "on delete set null" isn't feasible.

==> new version with changes:

- ProcessingData: fk to ProductionSteps now **without delete-action**,
  only nullable
- ProductionSteps: new **FOR-DELETE-Trigger** to set the
  fk in ProcessingData to NULL

When using this version, it seems, the trigger isn't executed when deleting records from ProductionSteps and so a SQL-Error occures.

Is there an alternative solution other than an INSTEAD OF delete-trigger?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 1:     create table ProductionOrders
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [ProductionOrders](
    [Sequence] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductionOrders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 2a:    create table ProductionSteps
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [ProductionSteps](
    [Sequence] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductionOrderCode] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductionSteps] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductionOrderCode] ASC,
    [Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 2b:    fk  ProductionSteps ==> ProductionOrders  (not null / delete cascade)
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE [ProductionSteps]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductionSteps_ProductionOrder] FOREIGN KEY([ProductionOrderCode])
REFERENCES [ProductionOrders] ([Code])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [ProductionSteps] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductionSteps_ProductionOrder]
GO

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 3a:    create table ProcessingData
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [ProcessingData](
    [Sequence] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductionOrderCode] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [WorkCenterCode] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [ProductionOrderStepCode] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [ProductionStepCode] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [Order] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProcessingData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductionOrderCode] ASC,
    [WorkCenterCode] ASC,
    [Order] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 3b:    fk  ProcessingData ==> ProductionOrders  (not null / delete cascade)
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE [ProcessingData]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProcessingData_ProductionOrders] FOREIGN KEY([ProductionOrderCode])
REFERENCES [ProductionOrders] ([Code])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [ProcessingData] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProcessingData_ProductionOrders]
GO

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 3c:    fk  ProcessingData ==> ProductionSteps  (nullable)
--
--              PROBLEM:    "on delete set null"  in the next SQL-command isn't feasible !!!
--                          executing the SQL-command __WITH__ including "on delete set null" causes an ERROR:
--
--                  Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 
--                  Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProcessingData_ProductionSteps' on table 'ProcessingData' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. 
--                  Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. 
--                  Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 
--                  Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors. 
--
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE [ProcessingData]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProcessingData_ProductionSteps] FOREIGN KEY([ProductionOrderStepCode], [ProductionStepCode])
-- REFERENCES [ProductionSteps] ([ProductionOrderCode], [Code])  on delete set null
   REFERENCES [ProductionSteps] ([ProductionOrderCode], [Code])
GO

ALTER TABLE [ProcessingData] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProcessingData_ProductionSteps]
GO

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 4:     create new trigger for table  ProductionSteps  instead of "on delete set null"
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER [TRG_ProcessingData_ProductionStepsDelete]
ON [ProductionSteps]
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE [ProcessingData]
    SET [ProductionOrderStepCode] = NULL, [ProductionStepCode] = NULL
    FROM [ProcessingData] PD
    INNER JOIN DELETED D
    ON PD.ProductionOrderStepCode = D.ProductionOrderCode
    AND PD.ProductionStepCode = D.Code
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [ProductionSteps] ENABLE TRIGGER [TRG_ProcessingData_ProductionStepsDelete]
GO

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 5:     create some test-records in tables
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO [ProductionOrders] ([Code])   VALUES   ('po1')
GO

INSERT INTO [ProductionSteps] ([ProductionOrderCode] ,[Code]) VALUES ('po1', 'ps1')
INSERT INTO [ProductionSteps] ([ProductionOrderCode] ,[Code]) VALUES ('po1', 'ps2')
GO

INSERT INTO [ProcessingData] ([ProductionOrderCode], [WorkCenterCode], [ProductionOrderStepCode],[ProductionStepCode],[Order])
     VALUES ('po1', 'wc1', 'po1', 'ps1', 1)
INSERT INTO [ProcessingData] ([ProductionOrderCode], [WorkCenterCode], [ProductionOrderStepCode],[ProductionStepCode],[Order])
     VALUES ('po1', 'wc1', 'po1', 'ps2', 2)
GO

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--      Step 6:     Test: delete all records in table  ProductionSteps
--
--          Executing the next SQL-Command causes an ERROR!!!   It seems, the trigger isn't executed
--
--          ERROR:
--              Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
--              The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_ProcessingData_ProductionSteps". 
--              The conflict occurred in database "TEST_DeleteSetNull", table "dbo.ProcessingData".
--
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELETE FROM [ProductionSteps] 
GO
```